# Rails: can I use two nested map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def has_name? name
    results = auths.map do |auth|
                auth.role_groups.map do |role_group|
                  role_group.resources.any?{ |r| r.name == name}
                end
              end 
    results.any?
  end
```

This is a method in User model
1 user has many auths
1 auth has many role_groups
1 role_group has many resources

I used two map there, but it does not return results I expect. This is the first time I two nested map, can I use it like this?

Comment: you can, but what result are you expecting?

Comment: @llya I expect return resources which resource.name == name to results. Then check whether the array of results is empty by results.any?

Comment: @MarcoSong: Please add what is your expected result. It will help to understand your question better.

Comment: @MarcoSong: `map` creates a new array from the old array with each value being replaced by what you pass inside the block. In your case it will return a array of boolean values( like: [true, false, true] ). Please read more on difference between map, each, select, detect etc to gain further clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but the result will have array of array and it isn't considered empty.

```
[[]].any?
=> true
```

`#flat_map` might help you here

```
def has_name? name
  results = auths.flat_map do |auth|
    auth.role_groups.map do |role_group|
      role_group.resources.any?{ |r| r.name == name}
    end
  end 

  results.any?
end
```

Or you could change your solution altogether to more performant one with sql *(without seeing your models, not sure it will work)*

```
auths.joins(role_groups: :resources).where(resources: { name: name }).exists?
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!  I do not know why your first solution still not return the value I expected, but your second solution did.  This is the first time that I see people use sql query inside model.  Fantastic..

Comment: Do you know why the first flat_map solution not work? It should return true ,because there is a value in array, but it returns false

Comment: @MarcoSong well, not really, should work fine. Just double checked it locally. What values are in `results` array?

Comment: I did `puts results` , it just returns `false`

Comment: @MarcoSong looks like `results` equal to `[false]`. Which is why `any?` returns `false` as well

Comment: Hi, finally I found that I was comparing different data types...your solutions are totally correct. Thanks to let me how to use flat_map and sql inside model

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add a direct relationship between `auth` and `resources`. 
In the `Auth` model:
`has_many: resources, through: role_groups`

the has-many-through relationship can also be used for nested has-many relationships(like in your case). Check out the last example (document, section, paragraph relationships) in here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Then you can do as follows:

```
def has_name? name
  auths.includes(:resources).flat_map(&:resources).any? do |resource| 
    resource.name == name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use nested maps to get the Cartesian product (simple list of all combinations) of two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

l = a.map { |i|
  b.map { |j|
    {"a": i, "b": j}
  }
}.flatten(1)
```

`l` result:

```
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>1, :b=>5}, {:a=>1, :b=>6}, {:a=>2, :b=>4}, {:a=>2, :b=>5}, {:a=>2, :b=>6}, {:a=>3, :b=>4}, {:a=>3, :b=>5}, {:a=>3, :b=>6}]
```